# Каким образом можно плавно изменить высоту UITableViewCell с заменой содержимого?

Tags: анимация, uitableview, swift4, ios10

Есть UITableViewCell с некоторым содержимым и определенной высотой. При определенном действии пользователя происходит .reloadData() и ячейка заменяется на другую с чуть другим содержимым и уже другой высотой (которая может быть больше или меньше). При этом высота меняется резко.

Как сделать это действие (замена содержимого ячейки и изменение ее высоты) растянутым во времени и с плавной анимацией, чтобы избежать резкого переключения ячеек и "дергания" таблицы?

Comment: У Вас ячейка при этом совершенно другая или только другие данные?

Comment: @VAndrJ другая ячейка. при "переключении" ячейки также изменяется количество ячеек в таблице (добавляются/убираются в конец таблицы)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для красивого изменения размера ячеек/замены контента необходимо немного больше действий, чем `.reloadData()`

Вариант 1. Все сделать вручную. Для этого необходимо определить что и как изменено в `dataSource` и обновить таблицу:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
// MARK: - Здесь заменяем/добавляем/удаляем ячейки
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Вариант 2. Использовать библиотеку. Их полно, можно что-то из Rx вроде RxSwift&RxCocoa / Bond. Но очень удобная, легкая и простая в использовании [Differ](https://github.com/tonyarnold/Differ). Всего одна строчка:

```
tableView.animateRowChanges(oldData: oldData, newData: newData)
```

И получаем результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]